# Do CSS libraries like Bootsrap hurt SEO and Google rankings?

Tags: seo, css, search-results, bootstrap

Recently one of my coworkers, insisted on that i should rework a project, just because I used Bootstrap as a grid system. He argued

> "that usage of CSS libraries (especially Bootstrap) is the one of main
> reasons for dropping positions in Google SERP"

Is there any supporting articles on this topic? What is the effect of CSS libraries on SEO?

I suspect that valid CSS does not affect SEO whatsoever.

Comment: How does Twitter do in in Google SERP, they authored Bootstrap :-)  There's really no logic in that because Bootstrap is one of the most common frameworks, and its resource files are typically cached in CDN's (if not linked to otherwise). A more valid assertion would be that the subject of SEO is filled with more myths than any other...

Comment: Valid CSS is valid CSS no matter how it is generated.

Comment: CSS is CSS. Crawlers don't see part of it and realize "hey, this is a library", they just see CSS.

Comment: The only way a library can affect SEO is if it slows down load time, e.g. if it is very larger or you are including it from a slow CDN/server. The full Bootstrap framework library can be large, so to optimise your project just make sure you're not including the whole framework if you are only using grids, for example. make sure its minimised and being served from a fast CDN.

Answer (score 2):

Technically speaking it doesn't a CSS framework is just a set of styling classes that helps users to create website faster. AS for bootstrap ever since it was released it helped countless devs and website owners to have a responsive layout and believe me it doesn't affect your rankings. Your SEO ranking is determined with your content, page loading time, user friendly design, etc. Don't belive him if you think your website is looking good and have a fast loading time you don't really need to do anything aside content optimization.

Fun fact: almost 18 million websites are made with boothstrap and bootstrap holds a relatively high margin of 52% in total web designing frameworks.